# How can I query names using regular expressions?

Tags: oracle, regular-expression

How could I search for a specific pattern in a column?

For example, I like to get all user names that start with either letter A or B.

(btw: this is tagged `oracle`, but it might be interesting in other RDBMS as well).

Comment: Perhaps the question should be re-titled since the solution does not require a regular expression.  I added regular-expression as a tag.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your question doesn't require regular expressions:

```
WHERE name LIKE 'A%' OR name LIKE 'B%'
```

For Oracle, there's [REGEXP_LIKE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm); Postresql, there's [SIMILAR TO](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/functions-matching.html); mysql has [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html).  One thing to remember though is not all regular expression engines are the same, so just because they support regular expressions doesn't mean they necessarily support word boundry assertions, non-greedy quantifiers, or negative lookbehind assertions, etc.

Comment: Thanks. In my case, that will do. I also found this to work: `SELECT mname FROM names WHERE regexp_like(mname,'^[AB].*$');`

Comment: All you really need is `^[AB]` ... the `.*$` is superfluous